# How to clear all the current params of a current request (not to create a new request) in GWTP?

Tags: gwt, gwtp

I am using GWT for my web app.

Here is the problem.

I have a `currentRequest=new PlaceRequest(NameTokens.cust).with("ID", custID).with("name",name);`

now I want to clear all the existing params of  `currentRequest`, ie I want to remove "ID" & "name" params in `currentRequest`.

If I don't remove them, then if i do `request=placeManager.getCurrentPlaceRequest().with("otherID", otherID);` then the `currentRequest` will have 3 params as it still remember the other 2 params.

There is a solution, we can create a complete new Request

```
Request newRequest==new PlaceRequest(NameTokens.cust).with("otherID", otherID);
```

But i don't want that, I want to keep the `currentRequest`

There is no `clearParam` in Request object

How to fix it?

Comment: try gwtp [events](https://github.com/ArcBees/GWTP/wiki/Events)?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set the paramters to `null`: `currentRequest.with('ID',null).with('name',null)`

Also be aware that `PlaceRequest` instances are immutable (so a call to `with` will always create a new `PlaceRequest` instance).

Comment: You should use `PlaceRequest.Builder`